# Trajectories arising from certain Toeplitz systems, are they closed?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

A 2-d anisotropic harmonic oscillator's trajectory describes a Lissajous pattern whose frequencies are $sin(2\pi n/N)$ and  $sin(2\pi m/N)$.

Integer $N$, of course.  For what non-trivial pairs of integers, $(n,m)$, is the pattern closed?

Though I don't know the answer, it must be of centuries' standing.  It's pretty obvious that the frequencies themselves are algebraic and non-transcendental.  The question is whether the *ratio* of the two frequencies assumes rational values or not.